# windows event viewer order by date time

Tags: windows, event-viewer

I need to check events for debuging a service that has many events .

Windows event viewer sorts events by date time but there is a big problem.
for example

event 1 time is 12:32:11

events 2 time is 12:32:11

events 3 time is also 12:32:11

event 2 is  after event 1 and before event 3.
but because they have same time in (HH:MM:SS) format , event viewer do not show order correclty.
I think it shows logs with same time,alpahabetically or based on other parameters .

**does event logging save millisecond for windows application logs?**

if yes,
Is there any way or any third party application to view events log really ordered by date and time when  hour , minute and second are same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @chenjun for pushing me in right direction

Answering my own question to help people with same problem

unfortunately ,  Windows do not save event's time milliseonds part in windows log>application !

Answer (score 1):

if you checkout an event detail,in xml view ,there is a property named `TimeCreated SystemTime`

Comment: Thanks for your answer .I looked there and noticed that milliseconds are not saved
Times are like this 08:49:13.000000000